# Copying files from and to locations named in text files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ubuntu

I have text file file1.txt with content

```
./home/a/a1/a1.1
./home/a/a1/a1.2
./home/a/a2/a2.1
./home/a/a2/a2.2
./home/a/a3
./home/a/a4
./home/b/b1
./home/b/b2
```

and one more text file file2.txt with content:

```
./copy/a/a1/a1.1
./copy/a/a1/a1.2
./copy/a/a2/a2.1
./copy/a/a2/a2.2
./copy/a/a3
./copy/a/a4
./copy/b/b1
./copy/b/b2
```

I have created script to copy all text files from

```
./home/a/a1/a1.1    to     ./copy/a/a1/a1.1
./home/a/a1/a1.2    to     ./copy/a/a1/a1.2
........
....
```

and similarly for other lines.

here is the script:

```
file1='/home/superjaggu/Desktop/file1.txt'
    file2='/home/superjaggu/Desktop/file2.txt'
    while IFS= read -r lineA && IFS= read -r lineB <&3; do
    cp *.txt $linA $lineB
    done <$file1 3<$file2
```

but its copying file1.txt and file2.txt to the target directory instead of copying text files from source.

please help.

Comment: cp ${lineA}/*.txt ${lineB}

Comment: @MaheshKharvi thanks for the command any way to suppress cp messages where txt files are not present cp: cannot stat ‘./home/a/a1/a1.2/*.txt’: No such file or directory

Comment: Got it : cp ${lineA}/*.txt ${lineB} 2>/dev/null

Comment: Aside: Using a standard, newline-delimited text file to store UNIX filenames is bad form, because UNIX filenames can themselves contain literal newlines. Thus, there exist possible filenames that are impossible to store in this format. A NUL-delimited stream of filenames avoids this problem.

Comment: `cd ./home; find . -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | cpio -0dump ../copy/.` should be sufficient...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*.txt` is wrong. It tells `cp` to copy all files matching `*.txt` in the current working directory (actually it tells the shell to find those files and pass their names to `cp` if you want to nit-pick). Actually `cp` considers `*.txt` and `$lineA` to be input files and `$lineB` to be the destination directory. BTW you also have a typo in the variable name, the variable is named `$lineA` and not `$linA`. The corrected script would be:

```
file1='/home/superjaggu/Desktop/file1.txt'
file2='/home/superjaggu/Desktop/file2.txt'
while IFS= read -r lineA && IFS= read -r lineB <&3
do
    cp -- "$lineA"/*.txt "$lineB"
done <"$file1" 3<"$file2"
```

Comment: I want to copy only txt files. Sorry for that typo mistake.

Comment: @Jaggu, your question doesn't make it clear that the names are of directories rather than text files themselves, so what "copy only txt files" meant in your question was unclear until given working code.

Answer (score 0):

Finally worked:

```
file1='/home/superjaggu/Desktop/file1.txt'
    file2='/home/superjaggu/Desktop/file2.txt'
    while IFS= read -r lineA && IFS= read -r lineB <&3; 
    do
    #cd $lineA      
    cp ${lineA}/*.txt ${lineB} 2>/dev/null
    #cd -v '/home/superjaggu/Desktop'
    done <$file1 3<$file2
```

Comment: You want `cp -- "$lineA"/*.txt "$lineB"`. The curly braces have no beneficial effect in this case, so you can take them or leave them, but the quotes are essential to prevent splitting on whitespace and expansion of globs within the expanded names.

Comment: Similarly, `<"$file1" 3<"$file2"` -- otherwise, you'll get failures if either `file1` or `file2` names have spaces.

Comment: Notably, @Mecki's answer included some of these fixes -- they're important. Also, they're bugs that http://shellcheck.net/ would find for you.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy is correct. You should really use quotes around the variables otherwise a space in a directory name will break your script. Paths in shell scripts should always use quotes. And you also want `--` and be it solely because a directory name may begin with a dash (otherwise `-` would cause the directory to be interpreted as an option IMO).